# Only scroll when revealed div is actually off the visible sceen

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I am showing and hiding divs when a button gets clicked. So the users clicks "Future Calendar" button and below the button will be their future calendar. These buttons are part of a table (actually a bunch of divs arranged as a grid) and when clicking on one near the bottom, the future calendar is displayed below the visible area of the browser window and the browser scrollbar appears. i solved this by using:

```
$(document.body).animate({
    'scrollTop': $(targetDiv).offset().top
}, 500);
```

This works great except that when I am clicking the top item in the list, it too scrolls (when really it should just show because it will be visible on the screen immediately).

I have implemented the following code that I found in similar questions answered on this site:

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function () {

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
    //alert('top-' + viewport.top + ' bottom-' + viewport.bottom);

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

This gets called by:

```
$('.myelement').isOnScreen();
```

This returns a true or a false.

What I am trying to do is use this to conditionally scroll the window only when the item in question is NOT visible on the screen. The problem is that if even a TINY portion of the item shows on the screen it is considered ON SCREEN. How can I adjust the `$.fn.isOnScreen code` so that it thinks my "close" items are actually off the screen? In other words, I need to add something to some value to make the borderline items appear as though they were actually off screen so I can invoke the scroll.

I have included a JSFiddle that shows the code above seems to always think something is on the screen and visible as long is it is part of the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/mikemahony/wjzrc1z3/

**UPDATE:**

This application is using Angular.js to display the table in question. With some testing I have discovered that the bounds.bottom is always 121 no matter where on the screen I click. This must have something to do with how Angular.js lays out the screen using ng-repeat. Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: Try adding a few extra pixels to the bounding area?

Comment: What I am not understanding here is that as my JSFiddle shows, the div is clearly NOT visible yet the code returns a true